# Access application Using url in other Machine

Tags: eclipse, networking, mozilla

I have web apllication which runs in localhost using eclipse,i am trying to access that from 
other computer using URL...but the browser throwing error.

The connection has timed out

```
 The server at xyz.xyz.1.2 is taking too long to respond.
```

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.

If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.

If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the We
```

the URL looks like this:xyz.xyz.1.2:8080/MyProject/GetUserSMSAction and the server is 
running in xyz.xyz.1.2..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port 8080 is probably not oppened on your computer.
If your network administrator won't open it, try changing the configuration to use the port 80 and this will solve your problem.

Comment: I am the admin :P and i am running tomcat server in 8080...port i am trying to change url to http://192.168.1.2:8081/AroundYou/GetUserSMSAction

Comment: Changing it to 8081 won't help. You need the port to be open.

I proposed to use 80 because it is (almost)always open.